# Issues with PostgreSQL RLS Bypass Policy and Policy Behavior

Tags: database, postgresql, row-level-security

I'm working on a small SaaS app that uses postgresql and Row Level Security (RLS) to manage user data. I've set up a table called `account` to register users with RLS enabled. However, I'm facing issues with both the bypass policy and the behavior of RLS policies for the same table.

Here's the definition of my account table:

```sql
create table account (
    id uuid not null primary key default(gen_random_uuid())
,   first_name varchar(64) not null
,   email varchar(64) not null unique
);


alter table account enable row level security;
alter table account force row level security;
```

I have created the following policies:

```sql
create policy account_insert_tenant_isolation_policy on account for insert with check(true);
create policy account_bypass_rls on account using(current_setting('app.bypass_rls', true)::text = 'on');
create policy account_tenant_isolation_policy on account using ("id" = current_setting('app.account_id', true)::uuid);
```

I need to bypass RLS for specific scenarios, such as during user registration and login. I enforce RLS for actions like fetching, updating, and deleting profiles.

I'm encountering a problem with the bypass policy. When I attempt to execute the following query for a user login scenario:

```sql
begin;
set local "app.bypass_rls" = 'on';
select * from account;
end;
```

I get the error `[22P02] ERROR: invalid input syntax for type uuid: ""`. This suggests that the bypass policy isn't working as intended.

I'm puzzled because these policies are permissive and should be combined using OR, according to the PostgreSQL documentation.

My questions are:

- Why is the bypass policy not working as expected, resulting in the mentioned error?
- Are my policy definitions correct and in line with my use case?
- Any insights into these issues would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!